# Show animations on every viewpager change

Tags: android, android-fragments, layout-inflater

I want to show animations on every content of layout inflater. Below is the code that I am using but the problem is animations shows only on first page of view pager.

What I have understood so far is that animations on all pages content gets loaded on position 0 but I may be wrong.

```
@Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = null;
            if (position == 0) {

                Home.rel_footer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reward_points_circles, container,
                        false);

                YoYo.with(Techniques.ZoomIn).duration(5000)
                        .playOn(v.findViewById(R.id.circle_1));

                YoYo.with(Techniques.ZoomIn).duration(5000)
                        .playOn(v.findViewById(R.id.circle_2));

                YoYo.with(Techniques.ZoomIn).duration(5000)
                        .playOn(v.findViewById(R.id.circle_3));

            } else if (position == 1) {

                Home.rel_footer.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.qrcode_scanner_promotion, container,
                        false);

                YoYo.with(Techniques.Landing).duration(5000)
                        .playOn(v.findViewById(R.id.imgView_iphone));

                YoYo.with(Techniques.Landing).duration(5000)
                        .playOn(v.findViewById(R.id.imgView_ipad));

            } else if (position == 2) {

                Home.rel_footer.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.deals_promotion, container, false);

                YoYo.with(Techniques.ZoomIn).duration(5000)
                        .playOn(v.findViewById(R.id.imgView_iphone_left));

                YoYo.with(Techniques.ZoomIn).duration(5000)
                        .playOn(v.findViewById(R.id.imageView_iphone_front));

                YoYo.with(Techniques.ZoomIn).duration(5000)
                        .playOn(v.findViewById(R.id.imgView_iphone_right));

            }

            return v;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you should not apply animations in `onCreateView` if you want to see your animation on each page change. You should instead use [`OnPageChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) interface and apply your animation there once user has changed a pager (switching to another page).

A simple code snippet to get you started.

```
mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener(){

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected (int position){
        // Apply animations here w.r.t the position
    }

    ... Other overridden methods ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (arg0) {
            case 1:
                //load ur animations here
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```